# Calculating $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h}\ln\left(\frac{e^h-1}{h}\right)$ in an elementary way

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to calculate the limit of $$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{1}{h}\ln\left(\dfrac{e^h-1}{h}\right)$$
I can calculate this limit using Taylor series, and got the answer $\frac{1}{2}$. However, I want to solve this limit in a somewhat "elementary" way, not using Taylor series, Laurent series, or L'Hopital's rule. Are there any such ways?

Comment: Let $f(h) = (e^h-1)/h$ for $h\neq 0$, and $f(0) = 1$. This function is continuous by the well known limit $f(h) \to 1$ when $h\to 0$. Assume for the moment that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ as well. Your limit is *by definition* derivative of $\ln f(x)$ at $0$ (no L'Hospital needed for that). By the chain rule, this is just $f'(0)/f(0) = f'(0)$. So, if you can prove that $f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} (e^h-h-1)/h^2$ exists, you are done. The limit indeed exists and is equal to $1/2$. I didn't check how to calculate it without Taylor series, but it looks to me it might be similar to $f(h)\to 1,h\to 0$.

Comment: Question for close votes: how is this missing context or details? This is a very straightforward question, OP can calculate the limit using certain tools and asks whether one can do it without those tools. What exactly should OP do to "add context or details"? Show that they really can calculate the limit with the aforementioned tools?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{equation*}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{e^x-1}x&x\ne0\\
1&x=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{1}{h}\ln\left(\dfrac{e^h-1}{h}\right)&=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\ln f(h)-\ln f(0)}{h}\\
&=\left(\ln f(x)\right)'\left.\right|_{x=0}=\frac{f'(0)}{f(0)}=f'(0)\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\frac{e^x-1}x-1}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=L\\
(x\rightarrow2x)\quad&=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^{2x}-1-2x}{4x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{e^{2x}-e^x-x}{4x^2}+\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{4x^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^{2x}-e^x-x}{4x^2}+\frac L4\\\\
\therefore L&=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^{2x}-e^x-x}{3x^2}\\
(x\rightarrow2x)\quad&=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^{4x}-e^{2x}-2x}{12x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{e^{4x}-3e^{2x}+2e^x}{12x^2}+\dfrac{e^{2x}-e^x-x}{6x^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^x(e^x-1)^2(e^x+2)}{12x^2}+\frac L2\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac14\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^2+\frac L2\\
&=\frac14\cdot\left(\left.\left(e^x\right)'\right|_{x=0}\right)^2+\frac L2\\\\
\therefore L&=\frac12\left(\left.\left(e^x\right)'\right|_{x=0}\right)^2=\frac12
\end{align}

Comment: A fine manipulation! +1

Answer (score 2):

An elementary method is to bound the limit from above and from below. Try and bound $\log{(e^h -1)\over h}$ between $\log(1+{h\over2})< \log{(e^h -1)\over h} < \log(1+{h\over2}+\alpha {h^2})$ when $h$ is small enough and some $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\ln\left(\frac{e^h-1}h\right)=\left.\frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)\right|_{x=0}$$

Comment: This is far from sufficient for this elementary question. For example, in order for the derivation to exist, you have to make sure that $ \ln\left( \frac{e^x-1}{x} \right)\big|_{x=0}$ exists , however, it does not. $0$ is a singular point for this function.

Comment: checking that is fairly simple, since $\lim_{h\to0}(e^h-1)/h=1$. Of course, in the first place, finding the limit of $\ln(\frac{e^h-1}h)/h$ as $h\to0$ is hopeless if you don't know whether the limit of $\ln(\frac{e^h-1}h)$ exists. Thus, if you insist that determining whether the limit of $\ln(\frac{e^h-1}h)$ exists is *not* elementary, then the original question cannot have an elementary solution.

Comment: This question is basic. It's your argument that is not rigorous.

Comment: You can update your answer anyway you want but the problem with the question is more about the way you execute the solution, not the idea. Because the question is already simple.

Comment: I can make it rigorous if I wanted to, the post was just meant to be a hint.

Comment: So you can post it in the comment section, right?  Because based on the new rule of Quality standards in MSE, your answer does not meet the quality bar.

Comment: idk, you can post your "elementary solution" if you want to. you can disagree, but i stand by the statement that my solution isn't the worst thing in the world.